# question about dgemm test `_mm256_load_pd(C + i + j * n)`

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, column-major-order

In 'Computer Organization and Design' RISC-V version book by Patterson and Hennessy, 'FIGURE 3.21' shows that `_mm256_load_pd(C + i + j * n)` is `C[i][j]` which is weird at first glance for me (the code is similar to berkeley [code `dgemm_unroll`](http://wla.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/fa16/lec/18/code/dgemm.c) which is from one intel article)

code in the book:

```cpp
void dgemm_avx256(const uint32_t n, const double* A, const double* B, double* C)
{

    for( uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i += 4 )
    {
        for( uint32_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) 
        {
            __m256d c0 = _mm256_load_pd(C + i + j * n); /* c0 = C[i][j] */
            for( uint32_t k = 0; k < n; k++ )
            {
                c0 = _mm256_add_pd(c0, /* c0 += A[i][k]*B[k][j] */
                        _mm256_mul_pd( _mm256_load_pd(A + i + k * n), _mm256_broadcast_sd(B + k + j * n) ) );
            }

            _mm256_store_pd(C+i+j*n, c0); /* C[i][j] = c0 */
        }
    }
}
```

Then I read intel [`_mm256_load_pd` reference](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-8/mm256-load-pd.html) online, and the param is '256-bit aligned *memory location*' as the reference says.

---

Q: so `C + i + j * n` should be `C[j][i]` instead of `C[i][j]`. Did I make something wrong?

---

And I tested with gdb, it shows `C[1][0]` when run `_mm256_load_pd` second time.

Below is assembly code snippet temporarily with `-nopie` with some comment with `-fverbose-asm` and self added:

```
   0x00000000004035b0 <+48>:    44 89 fe                mov    esi,r15d ; _60, i
   0x00000000004035b3 <+51>:    45 31 d2                xor    r10d,r10d ;ivtmp.20 is `j*n`
...
   0x00000000004035c5 <+69>:    48 8d 04 32             lea    rax,[rdx+rsi*1] ;i+j*n
   0x00000000004035c9 <+73>:    4d 8d 5c c5 00          lea    r11,[r13+rax*8+0x0] ; *8 bytes
   0x00000000004035ce <+78>:    49 8d 04 d4             lea    rax,[r12+rdx*8]
   0x00000000004035d2 <+82>:    4c 01 f2                add    rdx,r14
=> 0x00000000004035d5 <+85>:    c4 c1 7d 28 03          vmovapd ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [r11] ; r11 is C + i + j * n
...
   0x0000000000403602 <+130>:   41 01 fa                add    r10d,edi ; j+=n
```

Comment: I've found some books take algorithms straight from old Fortran code, which are all column-major. Use of indices i,j is from that era. Matlab also.

Comment: There is no question in your post. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions. Edit your post to make it clear what question you are asking. Include at least one interrogative sentence with a question mark.

Comment: Thanks. I know what book say now. And I have updated my questions with question highlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for above comments.

The code is Fortran-style, although in COD book it says 'Optimized *C* version of DGEMM using
C intrinsics to generate the AVX subword-parallel
instructions for the x86.'

Mark the Q&A as solved.